# How to Check if the uploaded file has signature

Tags: javascript, pdf, cryptography, digital-signature

How can I check if a file uploaded through an input field has a signature? After converting it to Base64, what is the process to verify if it contains any signature?

Comment: Only a few file-formats have built-in capability for cryptographic signatures (thus can be signed). What file type are you talking about?

Comment: Well i will only accept pdfs

Comment: Decode it from base64 and load it using an appropriate pdf parser library that can check for signatures. Fro "outside" you can not determine if a PDF is signed or not, you have to parse it (and potentially verify the signature).

Answer (score 1):

After conversion of anything (PDF or not) to base 64 you will require at least 6 times the effort. So to detect one single word here are some of its fingerprints.

- L1NpZ
- IC9TaWc
- ZS9TaWcK
- cGUvU2ln

and you can see a pattern but how could you tell this is a match too.

- U0lHTkFUVVJF

Thus the only reliable method is permutate manifold the endless possibilities or reverse to Plain Text.

The secondary issue is that a PDF signature could be encoded or encrypted or both or neither or perhaps compressed, so the permutations become ad infinitum.

So you need to use a plain text string as a signature  and then its only one of three to detect.  This file was signed and is now not signed but still has the fingerprint of a signature.

[image]

### Answer

From a programmers perspective

So if it is 3 times or more (x9 x27 x87) to do a quick test then it will be faster to compress the base64 back to binary and do a single test there.

And for that there are several answers but this one is not a recommendation for any.

I would simply filter 1st based on "/Sig" then try to verify that signature.